# Routing using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have the following HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<p><a href="/">Main</a></p>

<a href="first">City 1</a>
<a href="#first">City 1a</a>

<div ng-view></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/first", {
        templateUrl : "first.html"
    })
    .when("/first", {
        templateUrl : "first.html"
    });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Then there is a simple first.html page. 
Now, my `City1a` link works and angularJS loads properly the page into `<div ng-view></div>`. Instead, `city1` link does not work and I have a 404 error.

When one clicks on `City1a` my URL is `http://localhost/myproject/index.html#/first`. What can I do to turn the URL in `http://localhost/myproject/first`?

Answer (score 0):

```
module.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        //...your routes  
} ]}
```

This is forcing angular to use html5 history api, which allow you to manipulating browser history and its not using hashes for manipulating with location.

Comment: It does not work. I don't have the 404 error but the first.html page does not load.

Comment: and which error was thrown ?